# Get custom events in schedule function azure app insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have to get all custom events that contain certain string on the name, with a scheduled Azure function.
Ideally I would like to send an email if a specific custom event have some wrong data.

Comment: You can try to use the alert mechanism in azure from Activity Log. Hope this link helps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-activity-log-alerts

Answer (score 0):

The built in alerting features don't let you do this (run an arbitrary query and alert if some specific condition)

However, a lot of people are using Microsoft Flow, and [there's some example scenarios there.](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?q=application%20insights)

Other people have created azure functions to do similar.